# DIV centered in Chrome desktop, but not Chrome mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, cross-browser, centering

Chrome is my primary desktop browser. I finally learned how to **horizontally center an absolutely positioned DIV**, using `right:0; left:0;`. This worked great in Chrome and Firefox.

Chrome mobile does not center my DIV.

An odd clue is that Chrome mobile shows white space below and to the right of the site. I set the html, body min-width to 650px, and that takes care of the white space on the right. But I'm afraid this is just a band-aid on a more fundamental issue I'm not getting.

I'm not sure if the white space has anything to do with my DIV not centering, but setting the min-width of the body did not fix the problem. Even with min-width, the DIV still does not center on mobile. It aligns left... seemingly within the confines of the non-white space.

**Update:** I suspect it does have something to do with the white space, because when I turn my phone horizontally, the DIV *does* center.

Anyone smarter than me have any clue as to what's going on?

I will attempt to post my code below. The class of the DIV that won't center is set to "PostCard":

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Haunted Bucks County (HBC)</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.hauntedbuckscounty.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.animate-shadow.js"></script>-->
    <!--<style><link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"></style>-->

    <?php
        $contents=file_get_contents("http://www.hauntedbuckscounty.com/style_theme.html");
        echo $contents;
    ?>

    <?php
        $contents=file_get_contents("http://www.hauntedbuckscounty.com/Tools/Carousel.html");
        echo $contents;
    ?>
    <style>
    .PostCard {
        border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
        height: 250px;
        width: 450px;
        box-shadow: -3px -3px 20px #000000;
        background-image:radial-gradient(circle farthest-side,#FDF6D7 0px,#DBD4B5);
    }
    html, body {
        min-width:650px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px; margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
<div id="Viewport" style="height:100%; width:100%;
                          border:0px #FFAA00 solid;
                          margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    background-image:linear-gradient(black 400px, black 15%, #0E0E0F 15%, #0E0E0F, #1B1B1C);">

    <div id="Header" style="height:50px; width:100%; min-width:650px;
                            border:0px #FFAA00 solid;
                            margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
                            background-image:radial-gradient(circle farthest-side,#1B1B1C 200px,#0E0E0F);
                            ">
    </div>

    <div id="Content" style="height:350px; width:100%; min-width:650px;
                            border:0px #FFAA00 solid;
                            margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
                            background-image:radial-gradient(circle farthest-side,#2B2D2E 200px,#1B1B1C);
                            ">
        <div class="PostCard"
             style="position:absolute;
                    margin:30px auto 0px auto;
                    right:0;left:0;
                    border:0px #FFAA00 solid;"> <!-- SETTING "right:" AND "left:" TO "0" HORIZONTALLY CENTERS ABSOLUTELY POSITIONED ELEMENTS! -->

        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="NavContent" style="height:50px; width:100%;min-width:650px;
                            border:0px #FFAA00 solid;
                            margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
                            background-image:radial-gradient(circle farthest-side,#1B1B1C 200px,#0E0E0F);
                            ">
    </div>


</div>




<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#BtnWeather").click(function() {
        $("#Weather").addClass("WeatherDegree0").removeClass("WeatherDegree45 WeatherDegree45Push");
        $("#Solar").addClass("SolarDegreeN45").removeClass("SolarDegree0 SolarDegree45");
        $("#Lunar").addClass("LunarDegreeN45Push").removeClass("LunarDegree0 LunarDegreeN45");
    });

    $("#BtnLunar").click(function() {
        $("#Weather").addClass("WeatherDegree45Push").removeClass("WeatherDegree0 WeatherDegree45");
        $("#Solar").addClass("SolarDegree45").removeClass("SolarDegree0 SolarDegreeN45");
        $("#Lunar").addClass("LunarDegree0").removeClass("LunarDegreeN45 LunarDegreeN45Push");
    });

    $("#BtnSolar").click(function() {
        $("#Weather").addClass("WeatherDegree45").removeClass("WeatherDegree0 WeatherDegree45Push");
        $("#Solar").addClass("SolarDegree0").removeClass("SolarDegree45 SolarDegreeN45");
        $("#Lunar").addClass("LunarDegreeN45").removeClass("LunarDegree0 LunarDegreeN45Push");
    });

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

**Update:** Here is the link to my site: [Why you no center on mobile?](http://www.hauntedbuckscounty.com/Tools/Environment.php)

Comment: Probably related to `min-width:650px;` in `#NavContent` because that width is larger than most phones screen resolutions.

Comment: I should add that I'm using the HTC One M7, which I believe has a 720 screen.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I figured it out. I **set my container DIVs to position:relative**, then **set content DIVs to position:absolute**. I can't say I knew what I was doing when I solved it, but I guess I know what works now. In the future, I will probably use relative positioning as much as possible until I have to precisely position content within containers.